# Eclipse not recognising jstl.jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am working on a web project and trying to use jstl library. Even after adding `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1` and `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1` jar files I am getting the below error.

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

I have added the taglib in my JSP code which is like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Please help with this. Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the web.xml also

Comment: Help! The expression language (EL, those ${} things) doesn't work in my JSTL tags!

The declared servlet version in web.xml is very important to get JSTL and EL to work properly. You need to ensure that you're using a servletcontainer that supports the minimum required Servlet version for the JSTL version. Apache Tomcat 6.0 for example is a Servlet 2.5 container. You should then declare your web.xml conform to the Servlet 2.5 specification, this works for both JSTL 1.1 and 1.2:  (Please refer::http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: How did you "add" the jars? What does content assist in the `uri` attribute suggest?